# How to set INetFwPolicy2::ExcludedInterfaces property

Tags: windows-firewall-api

I implementing basic library to deal with Windows Firewall API.
I faced with strange result with `INetFwPolicy2::ExcludedInterfaces` property.
I set excluded interface via `Firewall.cpl` and when read property I got array of some guids. I am not sure from where this GUID come. It is not Interface GUID. I select all interfaces from `Win32_NetworkAdapter` and there no such GUID.
Also when I try assign this value back I got invalid argument or not found errors.
This code based on [msdn example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aa364723) written on on VBS, but it really does not matter I have same error on C. Original example did not works either.

```
Const NET_FW_PROFILE2_PRIVATE = 2

Set fwPolicy2 = CreateObject("HNetCfg.FwPolicy2")

CurrentProfiles = fwPolicy2.CurrentProfileTypes

if ( CurrentProfiles AND NET_FW_PROFILE2_PRIVATE ) then
   InterfaceArray = fwPolicy2.ExcludedInterfaces(NET_FW_PROFILE2_PRIVATE)

   if (IsEmpty(InterfaceArray)) then
      WScript.Echo( "InterfaceArray is Empty" )
   else
      WScript.Echo( Join(InterfaceArray) )
   end if

   fwPolicy2.ExcludedInterfaces(NET_FW_PROFILE2_PRIVATE) = InterfaceArray
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your csproj file xml in your executing assembly (not necessarily the assembly that uses windows-firewall-api if it is referenced). For each configuration there is a `<PropertyGroup>` tag, and each should have a child tag `<Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>` (or at least the one that you compile with).

Comment: I do not use any projects. Just vbs file and cscript.